# Generics and Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, generics

I have this code:

```
List<Integer>[] intLists = new List[]{Arrays.asList(1)};
List<? extends Number>[] numLists = intLists;
numLists[0] = Arrays.asList(1.01);
double d1 = (Double)numLists[0].get(0); // ok
double d2 = intLists[0].get(0); // why java.lang.ClassCastException ?
double d2 = (Double)(Number)intLists[0].get(0); // I can do this way, but the question is not how but why
// the reason is in compiler! it adds implicin cast! after compilation code looks
double d2 = (Integer)intLists[0].get(0);
```

Execption thrown on last line:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
```

Why?

At runtime elements in `intLists` has type `ArrayList`, not `ArrayList<Integer>`. Element in `ArrayList` is `Double`.

Why not just return an item from the list?

There is no `Integer` at runtime, how it can appear?

Comment: `intLists` contains `Integers`, you cannot assign it into a `double` unless you explicitly cast it to.

Comment: @abkvandrd wat's in your `intLists`. Can you show ypur `inLists` data.

Comment: intLists - is Array, It contains not Integer! It contains ArrayList , which contains Double.

Comment: see:[link](http://s018.radikal.ru/i513/1412/ac/c46d64a699ac.jpg)
there is no Integer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both intLists and numLists point to the same array, containing a `List<Double>` at that point.

However, since the compiler thinks `intLists[0]` is of type `List<Integer>`, it will add a cast to `Integer` when you retrieve an object from it.

So your fifth line is equivalent to `double d2 = (Integer)intLists[0].get(0)`;
This will fail because `intLists[0].get(0)` is in fact a Double.

It is key to understand that after line three both intList and numList are the same and **your List with Integer 1 is gone**.

The reason you can come to this point is line two.  Here you assign `List<Double>[]` to an array of which the element type is `List<? extends Number>`.  This should not be allowed.  It's a known bug in the java type system and is the reason usage of arrays is discouraged.
See [this article](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?JavaArraysBreakTypeSafety) for more info.

If you try to do the same with Lists, you will notice you cannot.

```
    List<List<Integer>> intLists = Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList(1));
    List<List<? extends Number>> numLists = intLists; // compile fails here.
    numLists.set(0, Arrays.asList(0.01d));
    double d1 = (Double)numLists.get(0).get(0); // ok
    double d2 = intLists.get(0).get(0); // why java.lang.ClassCastException ?
```

Comment: I understand! Thanks!
The reasin is in compiler! It adds implicit cast!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The error is "Double cannot be cast to Integer" The intLists must return an Integer and it tries to do so.

It performs an implicit cast to Integer on the contents of the List element before returning it to be assigned to d2. This causes the cast exception.

Comment: intLists must return ArrayList, becouse it is Array of ArrayList objects

Answer (score 1):

Since you are creating the **intLists** with Integer, and assigning this list to a generic list which extends NUmber, will take only Integer formats.

```
    // List of Integers
    List<Integer>[] intLists = new List[]{Arrays.asList(1)}; 

    //This List will only acceptst the List of Integers as you are assiging Integer List to a generic List.        
    List<? extends Number>[] numLists = intLists; //This list.
```

So, the problem here is with

```
    numLists[0] = Arrays.asList(1.01);// Here is the problem.
```

add only Integer values to the list which would work.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, in my previous answer I did not notice the little trick you were performing there.

I think what happens here is that internally, the compiler has prepared a reference of type `Integer` on the stack ready to be assigned the result of `intLists[0].get(0)`. It internally prepares to auto-unbox an `Integer` into an `int` and then to promote to a `double`, based on the expected type of `intLists`'s members.

But in runtime, it gets a `Double` into that place, and cannot assign it to that hidden, to-be-auto-unboxed `Integer`.

When you use `(Double)(Number)` it interprets the required operation not as an auto-unbox followed by a promotion, but rather as a (compatible) assignment of an `Integer` to a `Number`, followed by a (potentially, based on runtime classes) compatible assignment of `Number` to `Double`, followed by an auto-unbox from `Double` to `double`.

Answer (score 0):

```
double d2 = intLists[0].get(0);
```

This statement is trying to cast Integer object to Double and then Double object is auto unboxed to double primitive. But in java wrapper classes cannot be casted to other wrapper classes. i.e Integer cannot be casted to Double.

you should try:

```
int i2 = intLists[0].get(0);
double d2 = i2;
```